# Disk utility says partition is unformatted, Fsck says Macintosh HD is OK

Tags: mac, disk-utility, startup

I’m having an issue with my Mac OS X installation. When I start up the system I see a circle with a line through it. I reboot into Recovery Mode by pressing Cmd-R and open Disk Utility. It shows the Macintosh HD partition (/dev/disk0s2) as being “unformatted”. I open Terminal, run fsck_hfs, and it says Macintosh HD is OK.

I can also successfully mount and unmount Macintosh HD with no signs of corruption. I have two questions.

Why does it have a circle with a line through it when I try to boot?

Why does it say unformatted when it clearly isn’t?

Edit 1:

I have MacOS High Sierra. Can’t update further. Not sure what version because I can’t get on to check.

`diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI NO NAME                 2.3 GB     disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         448.3 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:           Linux Filesystem                         48.9 GB    disk0s4
```

Edit 2: Oh my goodness! I completely forgot to say that I set up a dual boot of MacOS and Pop!_OS. That's what the Linux Filesystem is. I have opened GParted on Pop!_OS. This is what I see. It correctly Identifies /dev/sda2 (/dev/disk0s2) as HFS+. Disk Utility identifies it as CoreStorage for some reason.
[image: GParted]

Edit 3:

`diskutil cs list`:

```
No CoreStorage logical volume groups found
```

Comment: Please tell us what version of macOS and try to capture and report the output of `diskutil list`.

Comment: @Gilby answer away.

Comment: Can you add the result of `diskutil cs list`?

Comment: Was that all of diskutil list? And please do as @Jean_JD requests.

Comment: I suppose the partition type in the GPT is `53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC` and is suppose to be `48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC`.

Comment: @David Anderson that sounds reasonable, as I had to modify my partitions with GParted and it identifies partitions by their filesystem signature rather than GPT partition type. It may have meddled with the partition type which confused MacOS. I will see what I can do to change the partition type, maybe gdisk would work.

Comment: the complete output of disk0 on `diskutil list` and the complete output of `diskutil cs list` have been added.

Comment: Sure, use `gdisk`. The current code is `AF05` and (I think) should be `AF00`.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to @David Anderson for the solution.

I think the problem was that when I was modifying my partitions to make space for Pop!_OS, GParted changed the GPT partition type. I didn't notice at the time as GParted identifies partitions by their filesystem signature as opposed to the partition type. I used gdisk on Pop!_OS to change the partition type from `AF05` to `AF00` and it boots properly. Yay!

Comment: I think what might have confused Mac users is when you stated you were able to *"mount and unmount Macintosh HD"*.  Personally, I first assumed you used the `diskutil` command to mount, but you must have used the `mount` command instead.

Comment: @DavidAnderson yes, I just did `mkdir "/Volumes/Macintosh HD" && mount_hfs /dev/disk0s2 "/Volumes/Macintosh HD"` from the terminal in recovery mode.

Answer (score 0):

(too long for a comment)

There is something wrong with your output of `diskutil list`.

Here is a typical output for a High Sierra system with an HDD:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical): 
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *250.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            249.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
```

I wonder why you get Apple_CoreStorage instead of Apple_HFS.

Please post the complete output of `diskutil list`.

Comment: Might get CoreStorage because it was a FileVault volume.  Might get CoreStorage because it is an APFS container volume.

Comment: sorry, i didnt bother to open safari on the recovery system so I typed in what thought was important on my phone. I have now pasted the full output.